# how to insert image in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Is there a way to insert an image in a textbox? I'm working on a chat application. And I want to change the values ":)", ":(" etc. with icon images. But I couldn't find that how can I insert image in a textbox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use RichTextBox 
[Insert Plain Text and Images into RichTextBox at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/csexrichtextbox.aspx)

[Inserting images into a RichTextBox control (the OLE way)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/MyExtRichTextBox.aspx)

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 10):

If you are using RichTextBox for chat than look at [Paste](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23kah9ca.aspx) method

```
  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap();
  Clipboard.SetDataObject(bitmap );

  DataFormats.Format format= DataFormats.GetFormat (DataFormats.Bitmap);
  richTextBox.Paste(format);
```