# Use images instead of text in console application

Tags: c#, c++, assembly, fonts, console

I've got a Bitmap object which has some image (like fish or anything else) that I'd like to use instead of some characters.
For example, when user pushes 'A' from keyboard he will see a fish in the console.

- Note 1: I know that I can't manipulate parts of the console in C# and I don't want to. What I wanna do is to change font of character 'A'.
- Note 2: my font is lucida console 12.
- Note 3: It's very possible that my solution is wrong, so I'll be very happy to hear better solutions for this problem...

For anyone who cares about answer :

> After some research I've realized that I used to look at solution in wrong way and to manipulate character bits you need assembly(8-16bit) interrupts , for more information you can search about "int 10H:11 service" (you can insert a strings of ones and zeros and get result...it works but only in XP [command prompt] and below systems you need to use DOSBOX emulator also you need to use c or c++)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to insert image in a textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168177/how-to-insert-image-in-a-textbox)

Comment: not textbox...Console

Comment: Have you tried [Unicode emoji](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146668/beer-in-my-terminal-how)?

Comment: no don't need it ,I need something like manipulation of bitmap fonts...

Comment: Bitmaps and fonts are two completely separate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*The console is an operating system window where users interact with the operating system or with a text-based console application by entering text input through the computer keyboard, and by reading text output from the computer terminal.*" - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Subtext: Console applications are for **TEXT ONLY**.

Console applications don't support working with images by default.
You can work with them if you add a reference to `System.Drawing` as seen in [C# Console Application - How to draw in BMP/JPG file using GDI+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15137449/2596334), but not display them in the console window.

You only option, if limited to the console, are [Unicode glyphs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24233355/2596334) (aka [Emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji)).

Refer to [How can I display extended Unicode character in a C# console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15168565/2596334)